# How to sort an arrray based on some attribute of the item EFFICIENTLY

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, optimization

Imagin I have an array

> var arr = [  {name: 'peter', age: 50}, {name: 'alice', age: 50},
>   {name: 'zebra', age: 50}, ];

Now, I wish to sort them on their name. So, that the output is this:

> [{name: 'alice', age: 50}, {name: 'peter', age: 50},{name: 'zebra',
>   age: 50}]

The naive solution is to create an array of names and sort them and then loop through this sorted names, find corresponding item in the arr and insert into the new array.

I know this is not the most optimal algorithm and not the cleanest to write.

Can anyone do it more efficiently? Also, note that I am using JavaScript, so I am limited to  the libraries and inbuilt functionalities of javaScript which might be easier if we were using Java or some other similar language I guess.

Comment: This is almost precisely the same as one of the examples in the Mozilla [Array.prototype.sort() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `sort` function of the Array to implement your sorting by `name` like:

```
var arr = [ {name: 'peter', age: 50}, {name: 'alice', age: 50}, {name: 'zebra', age: 50}, ];
arr.sort(function(a,b){ return a.name>b.name; } );
```

You can read more about it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: This one is a great solution too. I did not know I could do that :P Thanks Dalorzo :)

Comment: The text sort is a bit better with `return a.localeCompare(b);` because it handles strings that are the same better and handles language issues in sorting.